# Create log history excluding some command in bash MacOSX

Tags: bash, command-line, macos-sierra

impossible to find an answer to that:
i would like to create a log history of my command line **automatically** without having to do anything.

For that i found some clues, i modified my .bash_profile
but i need to exclude some command that i don't want in my log like "ls, cd, etc." 
this doesn't work, and i can't d

so here's my code:

```
# log every command typed and when
command_out=( "more" "less" "cd" "open" "ls" "pwd" "nano" "man" "help") #array of command i don't want to save in my log

my_TEST=0 ##setup a var
FIRST_COMMAND=$(echo $BASH_COMMAND| cut -d' ' -f 1) ##get only the first command 

## test if the first command is in the array
for elm in "${command_out[@]}"; do 
    if [[ $FIRST_COMMAND == $elm ]]; then
echo $elm # does not work
        $my_TEST=1 ## if the command is in the array the var is setup to 1
    fi
done


if [[ $my_TEST == 0 ]] && [ -n "${BASH_VERSION}" ]; then
    trap "caller >/dev/null || \
printf '%s\\n' \"\$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')\
 \$(tty) \${BASH_COMMAND}\" 2>/dev/null >>~/.command_log" DEBUG
fi
```

if you any other ideas of how to do what i want i'm open

Thanks you

Comment: Just learn some "new commands": ' more', ' cd', ... (so by preceding them with a space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash automatically keeps a history of every command you type; you can use the `history` command to view it. If you want to exclude certain commands, rather than trying to exclude them from the log, I would skip them when viewing it, e.g.  `history | egrep -vw 'ls|cd|other|commands|here'`.

You can set `HISTTIMEFORMAT` to get a timestamp with every entry, control how many commands are kept with `HISTFILESIZE`, and if you really want to keep some commands out instead of just not seeing them when you look, you can list them in `HISTIGNORE`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Using-History-Interactively.html.

Comment: There's also `HISTIGNORE` if the goal is to keep the given commands out of the history.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what i exactly want is this to be automatically.
I meant that everytime i open a new shell all the command line are automatically written in a log_file without anything else to do

Comment: It's already automatic... I was talking about commands you could run to view the log, and I'm not sure how you were planning on accessing it without running any commands, but it is stored in a file, namely `~/.bash_history`. Also, the idea behind `HISTIGNORE` and friends is that you usually set them once in your `~/.bashrc`, not manually every time you start a shell.

Comment: ok thanks a lot Mark, i completed it with some other research !

Answer (score 0):

Your `~/.bash_history` file should already contain your complete command history. You could use something like 

`cat ~/.bash_history | grep -v cd | egrep -v 'cd|ls|...'`

to filter out the commands you're not interested in.

So for the list you specified:

`cat ~/.bash_history | egrep -v 'more|less|cd|open|ls|pwd|nano|man|help'`

Answer (score 0):

I completed Mark Reed answer with what i precisely wanted. Here is my code:

```
# changes the .bash_history file mode to append
shopt -s histappend

#configures the history -a command to be run at each shell prompt. The -a immediately writes the current/new lines to the history file.
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;$PROMPT_COMMAND"

#list of command i don't want in my history
HISTIGNORE='ls*:exit:pwd:clear:cd*:man*:more*:less*:head*:tail*:nano*:open*:help*'

#set no limit to the history file size
HISTSIZE= HISTFILESIZE=
```